# How to override icon class after plugin is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, visual-studio-2013

I am using dhtmlxTreeview: https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTreeView/

I need to override an icon that is in a CSS file. If I go to the CSS file and override class, it is updated in the browser.

But when I run the first time and the pluging reloads again, the plugin doesn't respect the CSS override even if I use the `!important` keyword.

How can I override that icon file?

I need to change this:

```
i.dhxtreeview_icon.dhxtreeview_icon_file {
    background-image:url(imgs/dhxtreeview_web/icon_file.gif);
}
```

To this:

```
i.dhxtreeview_icon.dhxtreeview_icon_file {
    background-image:url(imgs/dhxtreeview_web/icon_folder_closed.gif) !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you paste a little HTML code?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to link your CSS file *after* the library's. This will make CSS's native specificity override the library's styles with yours.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/zk4t2t8a/

```
<style>
  div {
    background: red;
  }
</style>
<style>
  div {
    background: green;
  }
</style>
<div>
    Test
</div>
```

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: that is not the way, because the plugin is loaded after a page is loaded, thanks

Comment: Why don't you go into the plugin files and change the image? Or is the new image also part of the plugin files? Also I believe adding `!important` to your CSS style won't make the plugin override it, but I'm not sure on that. You could also just change the plugin's code but I would read the License first.